# Is it possible to connect a MacBook Pro and a Windows box directly using a Gigabit LAN cable?

Tags: networking, lan, teamviewer

I'm using TeamViewer to remotely access a Windows computer from my MacBook Pro, allowing me to use the MacBook's screen, touchpad and keyboard to control the Windows box. Obviously, the frame rate is small and the video quality is lacking. **Is it possible for me to use a Gigabit LAN cable to connect both machines and get a 30 fps lossless stream of my desktop's screen on my MacBook?**

Note most tutorials I've found explain how to use a cable to share a directory between the two computers, which isn't exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Lossless in terms of not dropping any frames, or lossless in terms of not seeing any compression artifacts? The former might be possible, but the latter probably isn't. Also, why 30fps? If you're doing this to watch video, 30fps is okay, but the compression story gets worse because lossless video codecs only get around 2:1 compression on arbitrary video. If you're doing this to remotely do general computing, then 30fps is going to be ugly, with super juddery scrolling, etc. You want 60fps or better for interactive computer use. One last question: What resolution is your Windows PC's screen?

Comment: …I ask because losslessly-compressed arbitrary 1080p30 video would take up about 3/4ths of a gigabit by my calculations. If your Windows PC's screen is higher res than 1920x1080, you probably won't be able to fit losslessly compressed video of it into a 1 gigabit link.

Comment: This cannot be done with TeamViewer.  It absolutely can be done software like VMWare View, and there are similar solutions targeted for other purposes [Shadow](https://shdw.me/), but both require dedicated hardware for hardware virtualization.  Most of these solutions would provide practically any resolution you want, provided, you have the money to burn.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible? - yes. Microsoft Remote Desktop, freeware, Apple App Store.
Can you get 30 fps lossless? - no. RDC-type apps are simply not prioritised to do high-res video.

The connectivity setup, however, is exactly the same as for file-sharing. Each machine simply needs to know the IP address of the other [& to keep things really simple, have them on the same subnet]
If they already share the same LAN setup, then wiring them directly won't gain you any speed; it would be simpler to leave them as they are so each can also still access the internet/rest of the LAN.

Comment: I can only recommend MS RDP over teamviewer. the framerate is really good even over WiFi, I'm able to watch youtube videos without noticing. Although the delay might be noticeable, it's not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you connect any two network devices directly together.  There are a few caveats, though.  First, you have to properly configure their IP settings manually to communicate with each other.  Secondly, their ethernet ports need to be autosensing, otherwise you will need a crossover ethernet cable.

However, you are asking for lossless video over the connection.  TeamViewer is not designed for playing videos or games over the connection.  It doesnt send entire frames over the connection.  It is sends *changes* of the desktop over the connection.  While I do believe there are settings to increase TeamViewers video quality, you arent going to get perfection.

Comment: @MaiaVictor https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+connect+directly+to+other+computers+using+ethernet+cable&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje-YDBs5jfAhXIuVkKHSUjCvcQBQgrKAA&biw=1200&bih=585

Comment: Yes, if you actually check those tutorials and videos you'll see they address how to share directories between both computers, which is not what I'm trying to do. Again, I'm trying to share the screen through it; if TeamViewer isn't suited for this purpose, any keyword or pointer about what is would be appreciated.

Comment: @MaiaVictor one thing has nothing to do with the other.  You want to learn how to connect two machines directly to each other, thats how you do it.